# How do I calculate dot product of 2 lists using recursion?

Tags: python, list, recursion, dot-product

So for school I have this exercise where I have to calculate the dot product of 2 lists using recursion.
If both string are not equally long or if there is nothing in the list it has to return 0.
This is what I have so far:

```python
def dot(L, K):
    if len(L) != len(K):
        return 0
    elif len(L) or len(K) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
```

The output has to be something like this:

```
In [1]: dot([5, 3], [6, 4])
Out[1]: 42.0
```

So 5 * 6 = 30 and 3 * 4 = 12 = 42 total.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: I suggest making an attempt at it before posting the question here

Comment: OP did make an attempt and they posted it...

Comment: ``elif len(L) or len(K) == 0:`` - this does not do what you think it does. This is how it's interpreted: ``elif (len(L) != 0) or (len(K) == 0):`` You probably want ``elif len(L) == 0 or len(K) == 0:`` or ``elif not (len(L) or len(K)):``

Comment: `K`, `L` is not the way how to name variables in python. This naming is always killing me.

Comment: Have a look at this. Should help a lot :) https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/

Comment: `elif not len(L)` is sufficient, because of the first condition `if len(L) != len(K)`. If `K` and `L` have different length, then program ends at first `return 0`, otherwise it means, `K` and `L` have same length, therefore we can check just one array, becase we know that second has same length as the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def dot(k, l):
    if len(k) != len(l) or len(k) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return _dot(k, l, 0)

# recursive helper function that accumulates the total sum
def _dot(k, l, total):
    if k and l:
        total += k[0] * l[0] 
        return _dot(k[1:], l[1:], total)
    else:
        return total

# tests
assert dot([5, 3], [6, 4]) == 42
assert dot([1,0], [1]) == 0
assert dot([1], [1, 2]) == 0
assert dot([], []) == 0
```

Comment: This should be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a verbose answer, hopefully this helps you understand the logic of recursion.

```
def helper(x, y, idx, n, curr):
    i = x[idx]
    j = y[idx]
    tmp = i * j
    res = curr + tmp
    if idx == n - 1:  # checks to see if we are at the end of the array
        return res
    else:
        return helper(x, y, idx + 1, n, res)


def dot(k, l):
    if len(k) != len(l):
        return 0
    elif not len(k):
        return 0
    else:
        return helper(k, l, 0, len(k), 0)
```

We slide down the arrays in tandem, keeping track of the index. We check on every iteration if we have reached the end of the array which would be the `len(array) - 1`. If we reach the end we return the result, otherwise we continue down the array incrementing the current index by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def dot(L, K):
    if len(L) == 0 or len(L) != len(K):
        return 0
    else:
        return L[0] * K[0] + (0 if len(L) == 1 else dot(L[1:], K[1:]))


assert dot([5, 3], [6, 4]) == 42
assert dot([1, 0], [1]) == 0
assert dot([1], [1, 2]) == 0
assert dot([], []) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify this code by tossing those unnecessary `else` statements and get rid of the `total` argument while we're at it:

```
def dot(k, l):
    def dot_recursive(k, l):
        if k:  # k and l are same length
            return k[0] * l[0] + dot_recursive(k[1:], l[1:])

        return 0

    if (length := len(k)) == 0 or length != len(l):
        return 0

    return dot_recursive(k, l)

assert dot([5, 3], [6, 4]) == 42
assert dot([1, 0], [1]) == 0
assert dot([1], [1, 2]) == 0
assert dot([], []) == 0
```